# Finding out the total number of orders a customer made in ssrs

Tags: mysql, database, reporting-services

I am in need of help as I need to find out the total number of orders a customer made. However, I do not have the count for the total number of orders in a database so I need to know how to work it out, and put it in my table with no duplicates.

Due to the nature of the information I cannot attach Images. However, if a customer has rows of orders, how can I get it so that the total amount of orders, and not just 1 next to each order (as each order has a unique OrderId and OrderNumber)? Example:

```
#> Cust Name > Order No > Order Id> Total amount of orders.
> Gina      > 0123     > 4567   > 1
> Gina      > 8901     > 2345   > 1
```

How can I get it so that they layout will be like this

```
#> Cust Name > Order No > Order Id> Total amount of orders.
> Gina      > 0123     > 4567   
                                > 2   
> Gina      > 1234     > 2345
```

So far I am struggling as I'm not a programmer at all and I have little experience with SSRS.

Any help is appreciated.

The Query is:

```
SELECT O.*
      ,C.CustName   
      ,OD.[PartNo]
      ,OD.[PartDesc]
      ,OD.[Quantity]
      ,OD.[Price]
      ,OD.[Total],
       [myCount] = 1 
FROM [dbo].[tblOrder] O 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblOrderDetails] OD ON O.OrderNo = OD.OrderNo 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblCustomer] C ON O.CustNo = C.CustNo
```

Comment: If we can't see your data (real or otherwise), we can't really help.

Comment: I have put an example in, do I need to add more dummy data

Comment: Why not add an extra column to the SQL query 'mycount' and give it a value of 1. You can then use this to give you a customer count as a sub total once you've grouped by customer

Comment: would i have to add mycount to the database? Im sorry im really not great at programming im a networker

Comment: Not required in the database. Just add `1 as mycount` as the last column in your sql select list

Comment: I'm getting error messages

Comment: Is there a comma at the end of the preceding select item? If not what is the error?

Comment: Sorry, `mycount` works, however, as I have assigned the value of 1 all the orders are coming up as 1 order. Customers have multiple orders each with a unique order number and unique order Id. How can I get it so that all the orders are counted, and assigned to the Customer Name?

Comment: We cannot tell what's the data set and what's the result set (i.e. the result of a query)

Comment: okay let me try and see if i can apply some dummy data (I am still a student)

Comment: Okay so the result of the query is `Customer Name = Rolls Royce OrderNo = 019292 Order ID = 22422.                                                             Order No = 124992 OrderID = 1288745B                                                           OrderNo = 342673 Order = 244252` and then the next customer with their orders. I don't know if I am explaining myself correctly. The data set is **CustName, OrderID, OrderNo, PartNo, Quantity, Price, Total Price** . I just need to know the total number of orders that each customer made as one customer can have up to 300 orders

Comment: Simply group by **CustName** and then use this expression: `=Count(Fields!OrderId.Value, "GroupName")` .. I don't get where you're struggling with? Maybe it's good idea that you learn about *grouping*, have a google and educate yourself.

Comment: **The Value expression for the text box ‘myCount’ refers to the field ‘OrderId’.  Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope. Letters in the names of fields must use the correct case.** That is the error message that I get when I try grouping, Believe it or not I already tried grouping by customer name.

Comment: Remove the *myCount* column, not needed at all. Perhaps it would be wise to include the *CustNo* to your dataset to avoid problems with similar named customers. Then you create a `RowGroup`on the column *CustNo* of your dataset and name it for ex "Customer" Then You should be able to get the wanted result with this expression: `=Count(Fields!OrderId.Value, "Customer")`

Comment: And if you want to split this total based on the OrderNo, then you'll have to add another child row group.

Comment: Thanks Shall have a go!

Comment: It seems like you want the total of **parts** for each order, and not the times the client ordered, then you'll have to use the nested groups or group on both the *CustNo* and *OrderNo*. then this would be the expression. `=Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value)`. Which will be the total number of parts teh customer ordered for each order.

Comment: I want the total number of orders that each customer made. A customer can make up to 300 orders in one go. I need the count of the orders, however I do not want it to duplicate and every order they make has a unique orderNo, so I cant group by orderNo as it keeps coming up as 1

Comment: Show what the result is you're looking for... You want a table that has which columns? This will be the best. there are like so many different iterations possible for example: You want just a table  with 2 columns, the names of customers andthe amount of unique orders they made, so the quantity of parts dont matter? Then you group by *CustNo*(named "Customer") and use this expression as value of second column `=CountDistinct(Fields!OrderNo.Value,"Customer")`

Comment: C.CustName   
      PartNo]
      .[PartDesc]
      [Quantity]
      .[Price] [Total],    ** These are the columns**

Comment: Customer name is not duplicated, so all the order details are in separated rows and are each separate. Quantity of parts does not matter, All I need to know is the total number of orders that each customer made

Comment: Its still unclear man.. what is the final table you want to display make a demo with example data and posta  picture... I'll solve this tomorrow.

Comment: Would you mind if I emailed it to you?

Comment: I'd rather not. Just make it fictional, just so i can see what the end layout is you're looking for. This way I can understand what kind of grouping you want. Because it's rather confusing what exactly you mean with orders. And the other data you wish to display as well, has a big impact on the actual approach.

Comment: Figured it out last night. Thanks though